# How to encrypt data at rest?

Tags: php, encryption, aes

HOw do i encrypt data at rest? I know SSL encrypts in transit.

How do i integrate AES 256 bit encryption in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using mcrypt:

```
<?
// Encrypt Function
function mc_encrypt($encrypt, $mc_key) {
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $passcrypt = trim(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $mc_key, trim($encrypt), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    $encode = base64_encode($passcrypt);
    return $encode;
}

// Decrypt Function
function mc_decrypt($decrypt, $mc_key) {
    $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $mc_key, trim($decoded), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    return $decrypted;
}
?>
```

Read more about the library here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php

EDIT:

**If i misunderstood the question and you wanted to do this in mysql you can use the mysql built in aes encryption functions:**

```
INSERT INTO users SET name = "User1", password = AES_ENCRYPT("password", "encryption key");
```

and:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(password, "encryption key") FROM users WHERE id = 1;
```

However this is just aes128, if you want to use aes256 directly in mysql you would have to modify the source and recompile.

Read more about it here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt

Comment: is that aes encrypt and decrypt? Thanks Ancide!

Comment: Yes. MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 == AES 256. Clarification: "AES-128, AES-192 and AES-256, adopted from a larger collection originally published as Rijndael."

Comment: Thanks! but how do i put in the mysql_entry $variables to be encrypted or decrypted..

Comment: You will have to encrypt the values before you put them in a mysql query.

Comment: This answer isn't wrong per-se, but it's not exactly "right" either.  The IV you're creating and using is doing nothing (it's ignored in ECB mode).  If it *was* being used, your functions would be broken, because you're generating a new IV for decryption.  You would need to re-use the same IV for decryption.  You may want to switch to CBC and correct the functions for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about straight encrypt/decrypt of data then there are some good examples in the [php.net manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php).

You would then encrypt your data before inserting it into your database, you wouldn't encrypt anything through phpMyAdmin.